# Replace if else with Switch statement

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I am working on the code below and trying to use switch statement instead of if/else.
The problem is that I cannot figure out how to get the switch to work.
A few things a tried:
I know that every time an expression is equal to the case constant, the code then will be executed.  Example:

```
switch (expression)  
{
  case 1:
        // code to be executed if 
        // expression is equal to 1;
        break;
}
```

My code below has a similar concept, but I cannot get it display the calculation.  There are no errors, but it does not display the total price.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    const int CHEESE_PIZZA = 11;
    const int SPINACH_PIZZA = 13;
    const int CHICKEN_PIZZA = 14;

    cout << " *********** MENU ***********" << endl;
    cout << setw (9) << "ITEM" << setw (20) << "PRICE" << endl;
    cout << " (1) Cheese Pizza" << setw (8) << "$" 
            << CHEESE_PIZZA << endl;
    cout << " (2) Spinach Pizza" << setw (7) << "$" 
            << SPINACH_PIZZA << endl;
    cout << " (3) Chicken Pizza" << setw (7) << "$" 
            << CHICKEN_PIZZA << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "What would you like? ";
    int option;
    cin >> option;
    cout << "You picked pizza option " << option << endl;

    cout << "How many orders? ";
    int quantity;
    cin >> quantity;
    cout << "You choose quantity " << quantity << endl;

    int price;
    switch (option)
    {
    case 1:
        price = CHEESE_PIZZA;
        break;
    case 2:
        price = SPINACH_PIZZA;
        break;
    case 3: 
        price = CHICKEN_PIZZA;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Please select valid item from menu. " << endl;
    
    }
        return 1;
    int amount = price * quantity;
    cout << "Your Bill: $ " << amount << endl;
    
    cout << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

I am confused about the output for any input other than 1, 2, and 3 in case 4.

The if/else statement works:

```
int price;
if (option == 1) price = CHEESE_PIZZA;
else if (option == 2) price = SPINACH_PIZZA;
else if (option == 3) price = CHICKEN_PIZZA;
else {
cout << "Please select valid item from menu. " << endl;
return 1;
}
```

Comment: In your `switch` version, the `return 1;` statement happens no matter what you choose.

Comment: I know you're a beginner but you're gonna get downvoted because of the elementary nature of this question. That's how SO is unfortunately, I get downvoted all the time, it sucks so much. Some observations - you're missing a case 3: break, case 4: break, and default: statement. Every case needs either a break or return in order to emulate else if behavior.

Comment: I don't get your idea but you return before print the total price.

Comment: Try to simplify your code to reduce the noise. For example, don't ask me what kind of pizza I'd like. That gives me the chance to enter "crustless", which would mess with your program. Instead, use a line like `int option = 1; // Simulating user input`. Get the code to focus on just the `switch`. Who knows? Sometimes creating a good [mre] leads to the answer before the question is asked.

Comment: @JonathanMa thanks for the comment.  I actually don't care about downvote.  I am more concerned about the learning piece.  I actually forgot to add the break under case 3 and will change case 4 to default.  With those changes, still no total.

Comment: you also need to parse option to an integer, I believe. I don't think you can store input with cin as an int. @TedLyngmo, i'm guessing that's true, I would never use a continue statement inside of a switch though - with an if statement, break will exit the loop, but with a switch statement, break will exit the switch and continue the loop. that's confusing to me personally.

Comment: that 'case 4' needs to be 'default'.

Comment: @JonathanMa `int option; cin >> option;` is perfectly fine if that's what you mean. The `continue` alternative is rarely used in code I've seen, but it is an option :-)

Comment: Thank you all.  I have no clue how I missed that return 1 outside of the switch statement.  As I said below, spent hours on this and that was very simple!  I added break which was a mistake and included return 1 and then case 4 was changed to default.  The code is good to go.

Comment: hm, i guess im wrong @TedLyngmo about the cin as well. I'm actually not a c++ programmer, i'm a python/java programmer, i dont think it's legal to do that in either language (accept buffered input as an integer), i think in both you must parse. AnsBekk you may benefit from a debugger. Look into CLion which is free for students and how to set breakpoints, it will allow you to analyze the flow of your program significantly, because you step through your program line by line.

Comment: @JonathanMa I agree.  I will try that although I am not sure if debugging will help since the code runs smoothly with no errors.  I will check out CLion.  Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: @JonathanMa In C++ `>>` is used for formatted input so you can create an overload for `operator>>` (or `operator<<`) to read into or print from your own classes if you want to. All the fundamental types are covered already, so all types of integers and floats can be read and written directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, from eyeballing, appears to be because you `return 1` outside the switch statement, which is why the code after it never gets run.

You should replace your case 4 with a `default:` label and move the `return 1;` into that case as well as add a `break` statement under case 3.

Comment: Who thought!  I spent hours on this and could not see that.  Thank you very much.  The default function helped with the last statement.  The break was a mistake.  Oh man!  I can't believe I missed that...